# why pywavelet Wavelet() does not accept all built-in wavelets?

Tags: wavelet, pywavelets

Any idea why `pywt.Wavelet()` gives an error for certain built-in wavelets? 
Is there a fundamental (mathematical) reason?

```
pywt.Wavelet(i)
```

exits with

```
ValueError: Invalid wavelet name.
```

for i=

```
'cgau1', 'cgau2', 'cgau3', 'cgau4', 'cgau5', 'cgau6', 'cgau7'
'cgau8', 'cmor', 'fbsp', 'gaus1', 'gaus2', 'gaus3', 'gaus4', 'gaus5'
'gaus6', 'gaus7', 'gaus8', 'mexh', 'morl'
```

From the doc of pywavelet

```
class pywt.Wavelet(name[, filter_bank=None])
```

> Describes properties of a wavelet identified by the specified wavelet
>   name. In order to use a built-in wavelet the name parameter must be a
>   valid wavelet name from the **pywt.wavelist()** list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those wavelets are continuous, so you need to create them by:

`pywt.ContinuousWavelet('mexh')`

and use continuous wavelet transform, which takes discrete data (array) as input:

`pywt.cwt(data, scales, wavelet)`

I don't know what is the real reason of this distinction.